# Concourse ci resolve docker hostname

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, concourse

I currently have two Docker containers running:

1- Is running concourse ci

2- Is running arifactory

Both containers are in the same docker network.

In concourse I use the artifactory resource as follows:

```
resources:
- name: artifactory-repository
  type: artifactory
  check_every: 1m
  source:
  endpoint: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory
  repository: "/docker-local/myapp"
  regex: "myapp-(?<version>.*).txt"
  username: bla
  password: bla
```

The important part here is the endpoint. I am using the name of the docker container here. I also tried a Network alias, But both options do not work. The garden container cannot resolve the docker hostname.

When I enter the ip of the Artifactory docker container It works. But this can change when restarting the containers.

Does anybody know how I can resolve the Docker name inside the garden containers? Which dns server does Docker use to resolve the container names?

EDIT: When I ssh into the concourse docker container I can ping the artifactory container by using the container name. But concourse jobs run in garden containers. I think the problem is the garden container cant resolve the docker container name –

Kind regards,
J

Comment: Are you using Docker-Compose?  That will handle name resolution for you.

Comment: Yes. When i bash into the concourse container I can ping the artifactory container by using the container name. But concourse jobs run in garden containers. I think the problem is the garden container cant resolve the docker container name

Comment: Ah.  Alas I know nothing about concourse/garden.  If Garden is some other container technology that you have nested inside Docker, that sounds like fun to debug!

Comment: Make sure your `--garden-dns-server` parameter is set correctly.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the correct settings? I already added 8.8.8.8.